# Amazon s3 multipart upload - not uploading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to do a multipart upload to Amazon S3 using java. I am using the code from the below link.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

```
String existingBucketName  = "My Bucket Name"; 
//For the below keyname, an object gets created inside my bucket.
String keyName             = "keyname"; 
//The file that am uploading to s3.
String filePath            = "F:/sample.pptx";
```

**Scenario 1:** The file to be uploaded is 31627 in size. I am using the partSize as 500000 to specify the individual part's size.

```
long partSize = 500000;
```

Since the file's size is lesser than the partSize the file gets uploaded into S3.

**Scenario 2:** The file to be uploaded is 908800 in size. I am using the same partSize.

The file is split into 2 parts with sizes as below.

The size of part 1 is:500000
The size of part 2 is:408800

However, I am not able to see the object key getting created in this case. The file is not uploaded into s3. I do not see any exception in my program. Everything works fine. I have no clue why the multi part upload is failing without any exception. I know it is used for uploading larger files however if I try for smaller files with relatively smaller part size it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working only when the partSize is 5 MB.

long partSize = 5242880;

I changed it to 4 MB and tried. It was not working. I also changed it to 8 MB and tried. It did not work. Only when the partSize is 5 MB it worked fine.

Comment: Hi Ramesh,
Do you have any idea how to upload the file with sse-kms by multipart upload?
I am able to do this with normal upload but I have no idea how to specify encryption with multipart upload.
I have posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328843/s3-multipart-upload-with-sse-kms

Answer (score 0):

According to the [multi-part part upload documentation.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html)

> Each part must be at least 5 MB in size, except the last part. There is no size limit on the last part of your multipart upload.

It's very strange that it doesn't give an error for uploading multiple parts smaller than 5MB (which happened to me during testing).